# Electrolysation at high voltage

Tags: electrolysis

I have a strange question for a crazy idea. I have no idea if I am right or wrong on this, but I want to ask it so I can understand.

I want to electrolyse water using the fewest amps possible. This is so that I can have greater efficiency while transferring and dealing with the power.

I know that electrolysis begins at around 6 to 12 volts. No problem there.

However, can I perform this at 700 volts or higher (admittedly separating the cathode and diode to prevent sparking) (or would it?) and use less amps?

I am wanting to lower resistance by reducing amps. This will allow smaller wires. And some other parts of this idea to possible work. I am just at the wall of my knowledge, and would like to start a new conversation to understand this.

Thanks.

Comment: Higer voltage == _less_ efficiency, not more.  The rate of the chemical reaction will always be proportional to the current.  The amount of energy wasted as heat will be proportional to the voltage.

Comment: See: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/2499/does-potential-difference-or-current-drive-electrolysis

Comment: that is `anode` not `diode`

Comment: You're going to want to put a whole lot of little cells in series, rather than running a lot of current through one big cell.

Comment: Just because you increase the voltage doesn't mean that the resistance will increase to reduce the current.

Comment: The reaction begins at 1.23V (you'll need more to get the desired current, but it does not contribute to the production), and the rate is proportional to the current. See @DaveTweed's comment for what you have to do in order to efficiently use high voltage.

Comment: Two hundred electrons go through, one hundred hydrogen molecules come out. You can't change that. But you can reuse the same electrons by putting cells in series.

Comment: Thank you for the reality check. I was not sure how far off I was. I wasn't thinking about specific, single use. I was looking for how much I could get out of how little. I am worried about resistance simply on the level of one electron does have some resistance as it travels. And if you can use fewer electrons, you can save a touch of energy. I will review the chemistry stack and keep thinking. Thank you very much for all of the responses!

Answer (score 1):

Electrolysis starts at around 1.3V you may not have notices because water has a high resistance.

One way to increase the current is to add sodium hydroxide to the water, this will reduce its resistance significantly (it also makes the water dangerous, so wear eye protection, and gloves, and rinse splaches promptly)

To use a higher voltage efficiently you need to have several electrolysis cells in series.

This could be a tank with several stainless-steel dividers that divide the tank into sealed slices, each compartment being in-effect a separate electrolysis cell and the dividers doiung double duty as both both electrodes and as the end walls of each cell.

this wirks well if you want Brown's gas, but if you want the individual components it means you need many more collectors. - using a low voltage and high current is probably much easier in that case.